# Looking for story where there is a virus making kids have powers

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book around a year ago, but I have no clue about the publishing date. It's part of a book series with 3 or so books (unsure about the exact number).

What I remember:

- The main character has the name Ruby (or some other jewel)
- There is this virus going around, infecting the kids (and only the kids)
- The kids (if they survive) get powers
- The kids that get powers are split into groups - red, orange, yellow, green, blue (maybe purple)?
- The red, orange, and yellow kids get killed (or most of them)
- The main character is orange but says they are green to survive
- The main character gets caught using their orange powers (mind control)
- She runs away and meets up with several other kids (a blue, a yellow, and another color)
- The four (or five) kids arrive at a weird camp led by a very famous kid with powers

Is there any book that matches this description?

Comment: I am certainly not trying to discourage  you to post questions here, but I found this book by simply googling - "book where kids have colour power", and the result was there including all the plot points you mentioned.

Comment: @shanu I don't know if my search engine is off, but my search didn't come up with "The Darkest Minds". So I posted the question. Apologies if it seemed a bit obvious. I welcome the input though. :)

Comment: @shanu - Basically popular every search engine other than DuckDuckGo is now personalized, so be aware that your Google / Bing / Whatever results likely aren't the same as others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[The Darkest Minds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10576365-the-darkest-minds)*** (2012) by Alexandra Bracken...? It's the first book in a [series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/168176-the-darkest-minds).

From the Wikipedia page for the [book series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkest_Minds_(book_series)):

> **The series follows a teenage girl named Ruby,** a 16-year-old girl with special abilities that she has only just begun to understand. **It takes place during the aftermath of a fictional disease known as 'IAAN' which killed most of the children in the United States and left the surviving children with supernatural abilities.**

The Wikipedia page for the [2018 movie adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkest_Minds_(book_series)) offers a summary of the plot which matches your description better than any other I could find:

> In a dystopian future, a contagious disease called Idiopathic Adolescent Acute Neurodegeneration (IAAN) kills nearly 90 percent of all children and teenagers living in the United States, leaving the survivors with unusual abilities. **These survivors with superpowers are imprisoned throughout the country. The children are divided into groups: Green (have increased intelligence), Blue (telekinesis), Yellow (can manipulate electricity), Red (can control fire), and Orange (have telepathy and mind control capabilities). Ruby Daly is an Orange, which means she has the psionic ability to get into people's mind. Children that are Red and Orange are considered too dangerous with their powers and supposed to be killed instantly, but she touches the doctor who is classifying her and puts the thought in his head that she is a Green.**
>
> **Six years later, Ruby is helped to escape her prison by a resistance group known as the Children's League to fight for her future.** Cate, a worker at the camp, provides Ruby with a panic button that can be activated as a tracker if she is in danger. When Ruby gets visions while touching Rob, another League member, she becomes suspicious of their intentions. **Ruby makes her escape with a mute little girl named Suzume (Zu), a Yellow. Zu takes Ruby to Liam, a Blue, and his friend Charles (Chubs), a Green. The three agree to let Ruby join them as they try to make their way to "East River," a purported safe haven led by an Orange named the "Slip Kid."**

The series has its own [Wiki site](https://The%20Darkest%20Minds%20Wiki).

Comment: you literally beat me by one second

Comment: @shanu - I know that feeling.